# Doctrine Hydrator nested data array

Tags: php, arrays, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Hi i want to populate a nested array using Doctrine Hydrator.

I a have nested array like

```
<?php

$user => array(
    'id' => null,
    'user-fields-ect' => 'some data',
    'person' => array(
        'id' => null,
        'person-fields-ect' => 'some data',
        'address' => array(
            'id' => null,
            'what-a-pain' => 'to type code here'
        )
    )
)
```

And when i hydrate this, i get an error `The identifier id is missing for a query of Admin\Entity\Person`

The error comes from `DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject::toOne`
which tries to find an record in the db, which is wrong, i want to create the record.

Anyone any idea how to solve this.

Comment: can you show the code you use to hydrate?

Comment: There is a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116720/doctrine-nested-array-hydration?lq=1